# CSS float will not work

Tags: css, floating

I have a REALLY weird situation with CSS on http://bit.ly/1Hwbn94

So, I want to have the red div with the title (title) right of the green box with the (later hidden) mobile menu button, but those two divs just keep to stay beneath each other.

Also, it would be nice, if the title (and the mobile menu button) is centered vertically (top to bottom).

Around those two divs there is a box called logo and I gave the red div the correct float: left; and also, I put a clearer after those two divs.

CSS

```
#logo {
  height: 80px;
  width: auto;
  font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 40px 0 0 210px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .93);
  padding: 0;
}
#menue {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  background: green;
}
#titel {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: right;
  background: red;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#titel span {
  padding-right:48px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="header">
  <div class="box">
    <div id="logo">
      <div id="menue"><img src="wp-content/themes/showcase-child/menue.gif" /></div>
      <div id="titel"><h1><span><a href="<?php bloginfo('home'); ?>" title="<?php bloginfo('title'); ?>"><?php if ( get_option( 'photography_logo' ) <> "" ) { ?><img src="<?php echo get_option( 'photography_logo' ); ?>" alt="logo" /><?php } else { ?><?php bloginfo('title'); ?><?php } ?></a></span></h1></div>
      <div class="clearer"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So, I just do not get it, while the red box will not float beside the green box. Do you see the error? Thanks in advance, mates.

Comment: Well you did set width 100% to the green and red div, they can't be beside each other if their width takes 100% of the parent container

Comment: No, I have set it to width: 30% and width: 70%.

Comment: You have but it gets overridden by `#logo div` because it is more specific than `#id` You can easily see this by using an inspector

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have these rules (not included in the original question) targeting all `div`s in the `#logo` container:

```
#logo div {
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
```

Take out the `width: 100%` and it will work fine, at the moment, both `#menue` and `#titel` are `100%` wide so they are wrapping onto two lines instead of fitting on one.

Also, you should put your `clearer` class after the closing of the `#logo` `div` instead of inside it.

Comment: But I have set #logo to width: auto; Where do you see 100%?

Comment: look at the styles at line 205 of your stylesheet and you'll see it.

Comment: @vega `#logo` does not equal to `#logo div`

Comment: no problem, try reading here about vertical centering: http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/

Answer (score 1):

Change the `width:100%` to `width:50%` in the `#logo div` section of your CSS.

Also, you have an unnecessary `float:left` within `#logo div` and you can remove `width` from #menue.

Answer (score 1):

take out the

```
width: 100%;
```

in your #logo div in style.css with line no 205 and it will wrk fine